system curve with two different pumps
I’m trying to understand how to calculate a system curve that accounts for two different centrifugal pumps in parallel, each with a different fluid and different flow rate.
These two lines will then unite in a single line, resulting in a new fluid with new properties and temperature.
Thanks to whomever might enlightened me !

The part of it which is a network analysis, is similar to an electrical circuit. The equivalent of Kirchoff's laws for voltage (analogous to pressure) and electrical current (analogous to mass flow). The missing piece of information that connects the two pumping lines, is the equal pressure at the junction node. From there you would work backwards to determine volumetric and mass flow in each pump. The mass flow after the two fluids combine is simply the sum by mass. Volumetric flows of the combination would then be calculated by taking into account the combined fluid properties.
